# USB keeps disconnecting...only for mobile devices

Tags: mobile, usb, driver, ipod, disconnect

Very strange issue, no results that I could find from google searches.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit. Everything Windows related is up to date, and so are all USB drivers. My computer is a laptop from Puget Systems.
My computer has three USB inputs; one USB 2.0, and two USB 3.0s. 2.0 versus 3.0 doesn't really matter though, because this issue happens with all three drives.

Heres the issue: When connected, USB devices are found, and recognized. 5-30 sec later, they disconnect, only to reconnect in a couple seconds. The cycle of disconnecting/reconnecting continues indefinitely. I have not been successful with keeping USB devices connected for more than ~30 seconds.

At this point, it could be any number of things causing this issue. But this is where it gets weird. This issue ONLY happens with mobile devices, and it happens with ALL mobile devices. By mobile devices I mean phones and iPods. I have tested my Samsung Galaxy S4, an iPod Classic, an iPod touch, an iPod nano, a Droid Turbo, and an iPhone 5. This issue occurred with all of these devices. The issue did NOT occur at all with my 2TB Seagate backup harddrive, my 1TB WD harddrive, several USB pen drives, my external keyboard, or my wireless mouse USB receiver that is plugged in nearly 24/7 in my USB 2.0 drive. My Xbox One controller disconnected 3 times in a row once, but that only happened once so it might have been a fluke...?

Anyways, what could be the reason for this strangely specific issue? Does anyone have any answers or has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Improper drive installation? Make sure your drivers are installed correctly. Try uninstalling and reinstalling them. If this does not work try to see if it is your USB cable or mobile device's port. (Test by altering to charge the device from a wall adapter) It could also be your computers port but you said in the title that it is only happening for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the drivers to the devices you are having problems with. (Oh someone beat me too it.)